# AWS - Security Groups not opening ports

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I created a Linux `t3a.nano` EC2 on AWS, I haven't done anything on the instance other than starting it and connect to it through SSH.

I would like to open 2 ports, port 80, and 3000, for that, I created a Security Group and added both ports to the inbound rules.

[image]

Based on AWS documentation that is all you need to do in other to open the ports, but if I connect to the instance and list the ports open none of the ports on my Security Group are listening, only 22, but that is open by default.

I am running this command to list the ports:
`sudo netstat -antp | fgrep LISTEN`

[image]

**Other Steps I tried:**

1. Check my ACL, will attach a picture of the configuration below, didn't change anything it looks to be fine.
2. Checked that the instance is using the correct security group.
3. Stoped and started the instance.
4. Created an Elastic IP and associated it to the instance to have a permanent public IP address.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any suggestions about which steps could I am missing?

Comment: SGs are there to filter traffic to/from your instances (like a firewall). Inside your instance it totally depends upon the program you will be running to listen on a specific port. Like you can run Nginx to listen on port 80, sshd to listen on port 22 and if these ports are allowed in SGs then traffic will be routed to your instance otherwise it won't

Comment: Thanks, Oli, your comment was really helpful, I ran a node server and was able to access the port 3000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking the ports from inside the instance. Security Groups (SGs) work **outside** of your instance.

You can imagine them as a bubble around your instance. Subsequently, the instance is **not aware** of their existence. This can be visualized like on the below image, where the SG is a barrier outside of the instance. Only if SG allow traffic in, then your instance can further limit it by using regular software level firewalls.

[image]

To open/block ports on the instance itself you have to use a regular a firewall such as `ufw`. By default all ports on the instance will be opened, at least when using `Amazon Linux 2` or `Ubuntu`.

Therefore, with your setup, inbound traffic for pots **22, 3000 and 80 will be allowed** to the instance.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation about the bubble helped to understand better the logic behind and between Security Groups and EC2.

Answer (score 0):

**Update - Response**

*I got to this point thanks to the comments above!*

I wanted to open port 3000 to host a web service, so I did all the steps on my original question, the step that I was missing was to run a server to do something on port 3000. After I ran node I was able to see the port open **internally** and was able to make requests to that port.

The Security Group remains the same, but now if I list the ports this is what I get: `sudo netstat -antp | fgrep LISTEN`

[image]